# how to use socket.io-java-client?

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io

I have experience of developing real time apps with **Node.js** and **socket.io**. Now I want to connect Java socket.io client with my Node.js server by using [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) from Gottox but I couldn't understand how to do it. I'm confused whether it has to be done in a Java Servlet Class or a main class

Comment: How do you want to run your java code? As a servlet or as a standalone application?

Comment: Firstly I want to run it as a Servlet, but actually I want to do it in android by the end. I want to write an android service with socket.io client and it will be connected with Node.js server. Can you help?

Comment: If you look at the [basic example](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/blob/master/examples/basic/BasicExample.java) you can see that all you have to do is `new SocketIO(..)` and you can start calling methods. It does not matter where you do that.

Comment: Yes I've connected my Java client with socket.io server. But now I don't know how to emit and receive custom events from java socket.io client. I've read about the methods on and emit of class IOCallback and SocketIO but couldn't understand. For example if I want to receive an event named **coors** and want to emit an array of Double from java to Node.js server, how'd I do that?